# C# implementing IDisposable just to clean up event handlers

Tags: c#

Is it poor programming practice to implement IDisposable for the purpose of cleaning up event registrations?

For example:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    TextChanged -= TextChanged;
}
```

Comment: No not at all a poor practice; rather a good practice if number of event registration is more. In such case, de-register them all in once place. So that, when GC invokes it can reclaim the memory space for the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends,

If you calling Dispose manually or using `using` statement, then it is fine.

```
using(var subscriber = new MySuperSubscriber()) {
   // some logic
}
```

If you expect `Dispose` to be called by finalizer - then it is not good, because finalizer can be not called, as you will have an "alive" reference to your component inside of event handler.